# Can I use a table view for a table containing many images?

Tags: qt, pyqt, qtableview

I have a table view in PyQt that needs to have an image in every cell.

I have used delegation of a label (and added a pixmap to that label). But the problem is when I add 12 cells (12 images of size 60x30 pixels), the table becomes too slow, and I need to have a table that contains hundreds of images. Should I be using another delegation? Or is it just not doable with a table view? If so, what is the best widget for such a task?

Any answer for Qt or PyQt would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you composite the images?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try using QGraphicsView for your purpose. Its much faster to render images on it.

One clever way to do is created a huge graphicsitem which mimics a table based on ur rows and columns count.

then add children graphicsrectitem item as each cell container.

lastly add the images as qgraphicspixmap item as children of the rectitem. this way u can make it quicker and also interactive since u can select them individually and also make them movable inside the cell by user by checking collision detection to make sure they are not pulled outside the cell boundary.

hope that provides u an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

[QListView](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qlistview.html) provides an *icon* mode where you can stack your images in a grid.